# Binary Search Tree run-time error on delete

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My BST occur Run-Time error.
When I run it as a test case it works but the server throws a runtime error.
(testcase1 : input - 18 7 26 3 12 22 30, delete - 18 22 12)
(testcase2 : input - 92 80 24 18 38 87, delete - 80 24 18)
Putting such a test case in the program works, but it doesn't work on the server.
Where is the problem with the code?

This is my code.

```
void deleteNode(int data) {
    Node* tmp = findNode(data);

    if (tmp->isLeaf()) {
        if (tmp->parrent->lChild == tmp) {
            tmp->parrent->lChild = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else {
            tmp->parrent->rChild = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
    else if (tmp->lChild && !tmp->rChild) {
        if (root == tmp) {
            root = tmp->lChild;
            root->parrent = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else {
            if (tmp->parrent->lChild == tmp) {
                tmp->parrent->lChild = tmp->lChild;
                tmp->lChild->parrent = tmp->parrent;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else {
                tmp->parrent->rChild = tmp->lChild;
                tmp->lChild->parrent = tmp->parrent;
                delete tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (!tmp->lChild && tmp->rChild) {
        if (root == tmp) {
            root = tmp->rChild;
            root->parrent = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else {
            if (tmp->parrent->lChild == tmp) {
                tmp->parrent->rChild = tmp->rChild;
                tmp->rChild->parrent = tmp->parrent;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else {
                tmp->parrent->rChild = tmp->rChild;
                tmp->rChild->parrent = tmp->parrent;
                delete tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Node* min = findMinimum(root);
        int deleteData = min->data;
        deleteNode(deleteData);
        tmp->data = deleteData;
    }
}

Node* findMinimum(Node* node) {
    if (!node->rChild) {
        node = node->lChild;
        while (node->rChild) {
            node = node->rChild;
        }
        return node;
    }
    else {
        node = node->rChild;
        while (node->lChild) {
            node = node->lChild;
        }
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a debugger to find the problem.

Comment: What's about the case where such node as both left and right child? For code you have, it will fall into `else {` case then `findMinimum()` will again fall into `else {`. You might have to also show the code of `findNode()` and how you constrct data struct from input testcase.